# Calculate date difference in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, utc

I write the code below:

```
var _MS_PER_Day=24*60*60*1000;
var utc1 = Date.UTC(1900, 1, 1);
var utc2 = Date.UTC(2014,11,16);
var x = Math.ceil((utc2 - utc1) / _MS_PER_Day);
alert(x);
```

I want to calculate the date difference between the two dates.The actual date difference is 41957 but after running my code i get 41956 ,one date less.What is wrong with my code ?

Comment: By my calculations the difference is 41958.

Comment: @nnnn http://www.convertunits.com/dates/from/Jan+1,+1900/to/Nov+16,+20   i check in more than 5 websites it is just 41957 day, i think urs also 1 day more.

Comment: Interesting: when I said "my calculations" I had just used Excel (2010), which seems to believe erroneously that 1900 was a leap year. So yes, 41957 is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an alternate code for the above which will give you 41957.

```
var date1 = new Date("1/1/1900");
var date2 = new Date("11/16/2014");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
alert(diffDays);
```

Reference : 
[Get difference between 2 dates in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: Your code works but i haven't exhaustively tested it.

Comment: Awesome. I've been doing it with math.round, but it's always giving me -0 and my logic was breaking. With this logic, I was able to fix my issues.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is calculating the difference between Feb 1, 1900 and Dec 16, 2014 ([41956 days](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=days+from+Feb+1%2C+1900+to+Dec+16%2C+2014)). [The value month should be between **0...11**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC#Parameters) (where 0 is January). Correct the month numbers to get the [expected result](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=days+from+Jan+01%2C+1900+to+Nov+16%2C+2014):

```
var _MS_PER_Day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var utc1 = Date.UTC(1900, 0, 1); // Jan 01, 1900
var utc2 = Date.UTC(2014, 10, 16); // Nov 16, 2014
var x = Math.ceil((utc2 - utc1) / _MS_PER_Day);
alert(x); // 41957
```

Comment: `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24` You used this twice. Why not just put in `86400000` or `864E5`?

Comment: @BenjaBoy what result do you get then?

Comment: @BenjaBoy - The code in your question is _not_ the same as this because you used different months.

Answer (score 1):

The months are from 0 to 11 considering 0 as January.
You may also use getTime method to get the UTC timestamp in miliseconds.

```
var _MS_PER_Day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var t1 = new Date(1900, 0, 1); // Jan 01, 1900
var t2 = new Date(2014, 10, 16); // Nov 16, 2014
var tdiff = Math.ceil((t2.getTime() - t1.getTime()) / _MS_PER_Day); // tdiff = 41957
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use http://momentjs.com/
it give you the best result.

```
const a = new Date(YOUR_START_TIME),
      b = new Date()

let diff = moment([b.getFullYear(), b.getMonth(), b.getDate()])
  .diff(moment([a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate()]), 'years', true)
```